# How can I get the target framework that is used in binaries path in dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-7.0

When I build the application the binaries are placed to a folder like this:

`../bin/Release/net7.0/..`

Is there a way to get the string "net7.0" from the running assembly somehow?

It is possible to get some attributes like that:

```
var targetFrameworkAttribute = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute), false)
        .SingleOrDefault();
```

But it does not return the exactly same string. Removing spaces and performing `ToLower()` will work, but I am not sure this would be the correct approach.

Comment: Answers may depend on what you want it for. If you want for example target specific code, then conditional compilation may be for you.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the string when you have it, is the question. The build process is *not* obliged to put binaries in this path; it could put them in `bin/Release/Potato` if the project file was so configured.

Comment: I am planning to target a file in the directory, so I need to construct a path, so I need this exact string. I.e. the code I am running is in another project/solution